# Finding the period of a SHO in special relativity (No ODEs)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator

I am trying to find the period of a simple harmonic oscillator, taking into account the effects of special relativity. I have found some solutions floating about, but they make use of non-trivial differential equations and I am not at that point in my education yet. I had an idea of how to solve it, and by using it I came to a decently nice answer. However, I am not sure if what I did is mathematically (or physically) correct or rigorous. So I will post an outline of the steps I took towards getting my answer with the question being whether these steps are appropriate, and if not, where the error lies and what other paths I could pursue.

We are given the inital position of the oscillator, measured from equilibrium, $x_0$ and also its mass, $m$.

So, what I said is that the period will simply be the integral of dt, $ T=\int dt$.

Next, I said that $$dx/dt=v \rightarrow dt=\frac{1}{v}*dx$$

Now, using energy conservation and the fact (this was given to me) that the potential spring energy is still $\frac{1}{2}kx^2$, I found that $$mc^2\gamma + \frac{1}{2}kx^2 = mc^2+\frac{1}{2}kx_0^2$$

I solved this for velocity to find that $$v=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{k}{m}(x_0^2-x^2)+(\frac{k}{2mc}(x_0^2-x^2))^2}}{1+\frac{k}{2mc^2}(x_0^2-x^2)}.$$

Finally, using this, I integrated from $-x_0$ to $x_0$, and multiplied that result by 2, to find that $$T=2\sqrt{\frac{m}{k}}*\int_{-x_0}^{x_0} \frac{1+\frac{k}{2mc^2}(x_0^2-x^2)}{\sqrt{(x_0^2-x^2)(1+\frac{k}{4mc^2}(x_0^2-x^2)}} dx .$$

I am hoping someone can give me a bit more insight into whether this is rigorous or even at all correct, and if not, why that is. Thanks!

Comment: I think what you have done is quite right, but i wonder apart from being a math exercise does this thing has some physical implications.

Comment: The next task was to determine if this is more or less than the Newtonian value, which essentially amounts to determining whether the integral is more or less than pi.

Comment: If you know how to take derivatives then you know how to check proposed solutions to differential equations. It is not necessary to know the toolbox for trying to solve differential equations *ab initio* in order to follow someone else's solution.

Comment: When you write and re-arrange $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$, you are involving differential equations.  And why isn't the quantity $x$ in your spring involved in the SR behavior?

Comment: @BillN, The quantity x is involved in all the steps I listed

Comment: It seems quite correct to me. For your second step I suggest you to expand the integral in powers of 1/c^2. The order-zero terms is $\int_{-x_0}^{x_0}(x_0^2-x^2)^{-1/2}dx=\pi$ which is the classical result and the order-one term will give you the first correction

Comment: In the classical spring-mass oscillator, the mass of the spring contributes to the period, up to 1/3$m_{spring}$.  And is $x$ the proper length or a contracted length? Which does Hooke's Law uses in a situation where SR is important?

Comment: @Bill x is the length in the lab frame. My understanding is that is what is used in Hooke's law in this scenario where I am measuring everything in the lab frame.